# Change background image from td in table with ngIf in Angular

Tags: css, angular, http

What do I have:
A td in a table with a background image

`<td background="assets/images/crew/sign.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center center">`

What do i want:
I would like to change the background image from the td in dependence of a boolean value `my_boolean`. If the bit is true, I would to display `sign.jpg` if the boolean is false i would like to display a different image `different.jpg` as the background image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what did you try yourself? Where's your starting point in code?

Comment: It would be easier to get an answer if you can provide a demo on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```html
 <td *ngIF="myboolean" background="assets/images/crew/sign.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center center">
<td *ngIF="!myboolean" background="assets/images/crew/different.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center center">
Ts:
myboolean:boolean=true;
```